# Spring and Hibernate eager initialization issue for multitenant application

Tags: spring, hibernate, multi-tenant, spring-orm

We develop a web application using Spring 3.2.0 and Hibernate 4.1.12.

The application supports "datasource based" multitenancy, meaning that each application tenant uses a dedicated datasource.

The datasource JNDI name is resolved at runtime, based on the name of the user requesting the application (the user name tells what tenant must be used). The resolution is done implementing the  org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider interface of Hibernate.

The Spring configuration (extract) is:

```
<bean id="tenantHibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.foo.bar.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.foo.bar.dao.hibernate.CustomConnectionProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

During the application deployment Spring initializes the application and the org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean instance. This ends up performing a database access. This database access fails because our CustomConnectionProvider returns a null connection. We return a null connection because at deployment time, there is no way we can identify the current tenant. Accessing the database during application deployment makes no sense. The stack trace we get is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantHibernateSessionFactory' defined in file [D:\Work\Java\apache-tomcat-6.0.39\webapps\ams-gate\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2287)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1752)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1792)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 139 more
```

I looked in the Hibernate sources and found a property that could disable the database access during deployement :

```
<prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
```

But it does not seem to work here.

**Update 1**: this Hibernate property does disable the database access during application deployment. But according to org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl from Hibernate 4.1.12 this property is a undocumented and temporary magic value.

Is there a recommended way to disable the database access during deployment to correctly support multitenancy?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hibernate accesses the database to check if the entity mappings are valid for this it needs a connection. From a hibernate perspective it does make sense to access the database.